# What are good *abstractions* for writing custom functions to autoindent code?

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation, vim

This month I've spent some time fighting with Emacs Lisp to try to get automatic indentation that better meets my needs.  It's striking just how low-level most of the indentation code is.  I've seen just a very small number of abstractions such as

- Search for the first instance of a regular expression that is not in a string or a comment

I suspect there are many more useful abstractions out there which would help write indentation code that is easier to understand and easier to modify.  (Even the abstraction I cite could be improved to "apply this function to these arguments repeatedly until either the function returns nil or point is not in a string or a comment".)

I'm working with emacs but I've tagged this question with vim as well because I'll take good ideas from anywhere.

If you wanted to program clean, well-designed, modular, custom indentation functions, **what abstractions would you use?**   (I would also be happy to see pointers to code that you think uses good abstractions or just is well designed.)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for something higher level, but macs 23 came
with [SMIE](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html), which seeks to solve this generally.  But it's for major-mode
developers, not to modify existing indentation behaviour.

**EDIT**: The major abstractions appear to be

- A fairly weak operator-precedence parser supplemented by a dirty-tricks lexer
- Each token gets the notion of a 'virtual indentation', where it would appear if starting a line
- Each token has a 'parent' which is the start of the enclosing syntactic construct.

The cost of entry appears fairly large, and the software is accompanied by this disclaimer:

> In practice, [the] default indentation style will probably not be good enough. You will want to tweak it in many different cases.

(EDIT ends)

---

What you say:

> Search for the first instance of a regular expression that is not in a string or a comment

is easily done by calling `syntax-ppss` and `re-search-backward`.

Answer (score 2):

Nice language-agnostic abstractions for navigating around a buffer programmatically are sexp's and syntax tables: if the syntax table for your mode is well built, you can move around with `forward-sexp` and `scan-sexps`. I'd say only use regexp's when these won't do, and even then use the values provided by them if you finally do have `re-search-forward` (see it's `BOUND` argument).

Also use `syntax-ppss` to discern easily if inside comments or string literals, or deal with character-escaping situations. See Emacs Lisp info node [Syntax Tables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html)

Granted, sexp's probably work well for indenting Lisp because everything is a list and can easily ask `(syntax-ppss)` a question like "how many levels deep is `(point)`?". With block delimiters like Ruby's `begin` and`end` you get into crazy regexp territory.

So to get `(syntax-ppss)`-like goodness in other languages you'd have a write a parser just for it. For example `ruby-mode` implements a parser and also take look at `nxml-mode` for an incredible example of this.

Also notice that you can do a lot with `with-syntax-table` as it allows allow you to look at the buffer from a different perspective temporarily. It's not indenting, but consider this example in http://github.com/joaotavora/autopair that allows me to ignore some parenthesis types

```elisp
(defvar autopair-empty-syntax-table
  (let ((empty (make-syntax-table)))
    (dotimes (char 256)
      (let ((syntax-entry (aref empty char)))
        (when (and (consp syntax-entry)
                   (or (eq (car (string-to-syntax "("))
                           (car syntax-entry))
                       (eq (car (string-to-syntax ")"))
                           (car syntax-entry))))
          (modify-syntax-entry char "w" empty))))
    empty)
  "A syntax table no \"(\" or \")\" syntaxes")
 
(defun autopair-just-for-delim-syntax-table (delim)
  "A syntax table that has \"parenthesis\" syntax just for DELIM."
  (let* ((syntax-entry (aref (syntax-table) delim))
         (other-syntax-entry (and syntax-entry
                                  (cdr syntax-entry)
                                  (aref (syntax-table) (cdr syntax-entry)))))
    (when (consp other-syntax-entry)
      (let ((retval (make-syntax-table autopair-empty-syntax-table)))
        (aset retval delim syntax-entry)
        (aset retval (cdr syntax-entry) other-syntax-entry)
        retval))))
```

Now, in a buffer with mixed `[]`, `()` and `{}`situations, it's quite different to ask for `(syntax-ppss)` or `(with-syntax-table (autopair-just-for-delim-syntax-table ?{ ) (syntax-ppss))` where the latter only counts `{}`. I don't know what language you're trying to indent, but this could help you do a reasonable job for indenting C blocks, for example.

Comment: The syntax table for my mode understands various brackets, strings, comments.   It knows nothing about any keywords, which govern indentation.  Also, the syntax table is not powerful enough to know that there are two kinds of "words" (alphanumeric or symbolic).  So I think I'm not understanding things well enough to follow up your suggestion.  +1 anyway :-)

Comment: I'm basically saying you have to write your own parser, but syntax tables, `syntax-ppss` and `scan-sexps` help a lot. Also edited answer to clarify the usefulness of `with-syntax-table`

Answer (score 1):

Some useful built-in primitives I know:

- indent-line-to
- current-indentation

Useful primitives that to the best of my knowledge aren't part of emacs:

- goto-previous-non-blank-line
- line-matches-p (regex)
- inside-p (opening-string closing-string)

Feel free to complete this list - I haven't found many resources on emacs indentation.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas at a *much* higher level of abstraction.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get much higher, being language-agnostic. I have thought about nesting levels, but that's usually deducible from the indentation and content of the previous line

Comment: If you are asking how in general to do indentation, you might want to decide on a number of contexts (such as block body, argument list, string, comment etc ), a function which determines which one applies and functions that will do the indentation for each of them.
Don't be quick to dismiss existing code as low-level or dirty-tricks. Do you want your whole file to parsed and validated each time you press TAB? Probably not.